# How to write a custom serializer adapter for Gson that I can use with .NET?

Tags: java, .net, json, serialization, gson

I've got a .NET Rest webservice which delivers responses in Json. I consume the webservice in Java. I use Gson to serialize to and from Json.

I've got problems serializing between .NET and Java when it comes to polymorphism.

I've followed this guide in order to write a custom serializer adapter for Gson for my classes that extends an abstract class:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/json-with-gson-and-abstract-classes.html

The problem is that Gson then generates the following:

```
{"type":"Circle","properties":{"color":"red"}}
```

The default implementation in .NET does not understand the new "properties" attribute. What I need the adapter to write is the following:

```
{"__type":"Circle","color":"red"}
```

How do I change the adapter to output this instead when serializing and who to deserialize it too?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by adding the following to the abstract base class so it's automatically serialized by Gson:

```
private String __type = this.getClass().getSimpleName();
```