# Serialise byte[] with Newtonsoft.Json and deserialise to byte[] with Google Gson

Tags: c#, java, android, arrays, json

I am getting an error deserialising a byte array serialised using nNewtonsoft.json in c# to a byte[] array in java (android project)   using Gson.
The error is:
     com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 10

the object I am serialising is

```
public class ServerMsg
{
    public ServerCodesEnum.PdaServerAsyncCodes CommandCode { get; set; }
    public byte[] data;
    public List<Extra> Extras;
    public ServerMsg()
    {
         Extras = new List<Extra>();
    }
}
```

The byte[] is causing the error.
The Newtonsoft.json serialises the array to a string ?
How can I make the two type compatable?

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804489/how-to-write-a-custom-serializer-adapter-for-gson-that-i-can-use-with-net. You can't expect two different serializers to magically cooperate :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use byte[] on server side use List this will work both sides.