# gson and references

Tags: java, android, gson

I've a small app in Android which have to comunicate with a server through a socket. The question is: can I use Gson to serialize the references of the object?

I make an example:
if I have a B class like this:

```
public class B{
    int n;

    public B(int n){
        this.n=n;
    }

    public int getN() {
        return n;
    }

    public void setN(int n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    public B() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and an A class like this

```
public class A{
    B b1;
    B b2;
    B b3;

    public B getB1() {
        return b1;
    }

    public void setB1(B b1) {
        this.b1 = b1;
    }

    public B getB2() {
        return b2;
    }

    public void setB2(B b2) {
        this.b2 = b2;
    }

    public B getB3() {
        return b3;
    }

    public void setB3(B b3) {
        this.b3 = b3;
    }

    public A(B b1, B b2, B b3) {
        super();
        this.b1 = b1;
        this.b2 = b2;
        this.b3 = b3;
    }

    public A() {
        super();
    }
}
```

and than I call

```
B b1 = new B(1); B b2 = new B(2)
A a = new A(b1,b1,b2);
```

if I serialize (with `(new Gson()).toJson(a,A.class)` the a object I obtain

`{"b1":{"n":1},"b2":{"n":1},"b3":{"n":2}}`

but I'd prefer have something link this

`{istance1:{b1: {"b1":istance2,"b2":istance2,"b3":istance2},istance2: {"n":1},istance3:{"n":2}}`

Can you help me?  I read a lot of pages but I didn't find anything!

Comment: I also spent a lot time in achieving this from the other way round, but couldn't find any satisfied answer. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195259/how-to-include-object-type-in-json-for-asmx-web-service-using-gson). Seems like there is no native support for this. However, if your server can help you to identify the object type in json, then there might be some custom tailored solution.

Comment: thanks for your answer.
I wrote also the server, so I can construct the serializer and deserializer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at GraphAdapterBuilder, which can do this. You'll need to copy that file into your application because it isn't included in Gson.

```
Roshambo rock = new Roshambo("ROCK");
Roshambo scissors = new Roshambo("SCISSORS");
Roshambo paper = new Roshambo("PAPER");
rock.beats = scissors;
scissors.beats = paper;
paper.beats = rock;

GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
new GraphAdapterBuilder()
    .addType(Roshambo.class)
    .registerOn(gsonBuilder);
Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

assertEquals("{'0x1':{'name':'ROCK','beats':'0x2'}," +
    "'0x2':{'name':'SCISSORS','beats':'0x3'}," +
    "'0x3':{'name':'PAPER','beats':'0x1'}}",
    gson.toJson(rock).replace('\"', '\''));
```

https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/source/browse/trunk/extras/src/main/java/com/google/gson/graph/GraphAdapterBuilder.java

Comment: Jesse this is the exactly think I need!
Thanks a lot!!!

I didn't find it because it's not documented, but it's very useful!

Answer (score -2):

JSON is a standard designed for data interchange. This way, it has some rules that need to be followed in order to "standardize" the communication.

If you want to use GSon to serialize data, you cannot change how it is serialized. That is the pattern

If you really want to produce the serialized data at your way, i think you will also need to produce the Serializer/Deserializer for it!

Good luck

Comment: thanks Renato,
now I'll check how to write the serializer and deserializer.
I thought there is jet a system, but I can write it if it doesn't exist

Comment: Do you really NEED the data to have this different pattern? I think you 'll loose too much time to write the serializer/deserializer. Consider use GSon...

Comment: You're right, I thought an easier solution: I'll write a middleware to convert each "complex" to an object with simple references, and then I'll pass every object like a list

Now I've to go, I'll you an example as soon as possible

Comment: the whole serialize/deserialize business of json, xml and what not is just too shortsighted. E.g. an 1:N or N:M relation of objects is pretty much standard and serializsation frameworks should not choke on this but instead have a proper two-pass handling with reference ids for this case. It's. not really hard to do this and there is not much of a performance penality. The "standards" are IMHO just too poorly designed these days.