# How can JSON be deserialized in Java when it contains $ref and $id generated by Json.Net C#

Tags: java, c#, json.net, deserialization

I have a JSON string generated using Json.Net C# library with this settings:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented,
                ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All
            };
```

Note the PreserveReferencesHandling to have references generated in json instead of the same object being copied (duplicated) on each object reference.

How can I deserialize the result in java ? Google Gson library fails to parse.

UPDATE:
The error can't help much in my opinion:
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 154944 path $.Tables[0].Columns[4].ForeignKeyTable.ForeignKeyChildren[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxGTT.png).Columns[0].ForeignKeyTable.Indexes

I'll put a small fragment of the json data, note the $id, $ref:
[JSON with references format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxGTT.png)

Comment: As much as I would like to help someone with almost the same name as me, I can't.... you will need to share what "fails to parse" means. Did it give you an error? If so, what did it say? If you can share the JSON string, that would be helpful too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gson and references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12978140/gson-and-references)

Comment: @DanNeely I want to deserialize not serialize, I'll have a look maybe it can still help.

Comment: Do you really need `PreserveReferencesHandling.All` or would `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects` be sufficient?

Comment: @dbc it dose not affect the output for me All is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a java library that I modified to be conform to JsonNet C# serializer format:

https://github.com/jdereg/json-io

Changed @id, @ref and @items to $id, $ref and $values and the string value in $id and $ref from JsonNet C# parsed to java Long (it is a number even in C# serialized format but it is as string type)

Maybe this can help others as well..

https://github.com/LucaGabi/json-io.git